# Trying to delete folders with in a directory in CMD but with an exclusion list

Tags: batch-file, exception, cmd, directory

I found this on S.O.:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad^|findstr /vxilg:"keep.txt"') do rd /q /s "%%F"
```

Where do I specify the folder path of the folders I want to delete?

Answer (score 0):

```
set "folder=C:\My Folder"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad "%folder%" ^|findstr /vxilg:"keep.txt"') do rd /q /s "%folder%\%%F"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) to temporarily change to the folder to process and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) to restore the original one:

```cmd
pushd "D:\your\folder\path" && ((for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad^|findstr /vxilg:"keep.txt"') do rd /q /s "%%F") & popd)
```

The [`&&` operator](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) avoids the following command(s) to be executed when your folder path cannot be found.